# Flash messages through AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

### The goal

I want to use `flash[:error]` in my view with AJAX request.

### The problem

I really just don't know how to perform that.

### The scenario

If a user's authentication fails, this happens:

```
flash[:error] = t('globals.errors.authentication.user-not-found').to_json
render :json => flash[:error]
```

The point is: in my point of view, in this case, `flash[:error]` isn't being used correctly. Perhaps the concept is right, but technically speaking, I can turn the flash error into a normal variable and the result will be the same.

Then I ask: **there's a way to use flash messages with AJAX requests?**

### The client-side

This is how I'm receiving the message from controller:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/authenticate',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response); // Here!
    }
});
```

### There's an error?

No. There isn't. As I said in the **The Problem** section: *I really just **don't know** how to perform [the goal]*.

### What I've already tried

Well... in the `success` property of `$.ajax`, I tried to put `flash[:error]` there, but it doesn't make sense because there have no errors yet - it comes with AJAX's response.

Thanks in advance.

### If flash messages doesn't work in pair with AJAX...

Using a normal variable (like below) it's correct/DRY/good practice?

```
error = 'User not found'.to_json
render :json => error
```

### TL;DR

I just want to pass from controller to view some quick and *easy-to-set-up* error message and I'm trying to pass that through an AJAX request. Can I perform that via **flash message**? If so, how? If don't, a simple/normal/string variable can meet my need?

Comment: What is the output if you temporarily hard-code the POST variables in your Rails app and visit `/authenticate` manually in your browser?

Answer (score 0):

The flash messages in Rails are just one-use parameters passed to the view. Usually a ERB or HAML template/layout checks for the variable and then prints the message contained in it. When using AJAX, you are most likely not rendering the full page and so this check is not executed.

You can render the error in a partial you are returning during the AJAX request (if you are doing this) but the better practice would be to let the request fail (return an error HTTP code like 403 or similar) and return an error message as JSON like you suggested yourself.

Look up an appropriate code here: (anything above 400 is treated as error)
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

```
render :json => error.to_json, :status => :403
```

or

```
render :partial => 'error_page.html.erb', :locals => {:errors => element.errors}
```

Access the message in your `error` part of the AJAX and display the text somewhere on the page or in a popup. (parse the response for JSON, or print directly if rendered partial)

```
$.ajax {
    ...
    success: function(response) { // do other stuff }
    error: function(response){
        $('#error_container').html(response).show(); }
}
```

---

long story short:

You can not access the rails flash messages in your AJAX return value directly unless you are either passing them manually or rendering them within a template and returning this rendered page instead of a JSON.